# how to annotate on an image in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, annotations

I have an image being shown on the screen in my app. I want to load a custom image as annotation (and unload the one at the previous location) at a specific location (on tap).

Can anyone kindly tell me what to do ?

Thanks and have a great day.

-
ahsan